# Build.xml issue

Tags: ant, testng

Selenium - ANT -TestNG

I have written a build.xml, where it produces a error stating " classname attribute of taskdef element is undefined "

Here is my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <project name ="AutomationScripts" default="test" basedir=".">
 <echo message ="Testing selenium server... Plz wait"/>
 <target name="startServer">
 <echo message ="Start selenium server... Plz wait"/>  
 <java jar="..\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar" fork="true">
 <jvmarg value="-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.0.200"/>
 <jvmarg value="-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128"/> </java>
 <echo message ="Started selenium server"/>
 </target>
 <target name="test" depends="startServer">
 <echo message="Test run. Please wait"/>
 <mkdir dir="out" />
 <java classname="RosettastoneMain" classpath="..\AutomationScripts\bin" 
 dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin">
 <classpath>
<fileset dir="..\AutomationScripts\lib" includes="*.*"/>
 </classpatha></java>
 <taskdef name="testng" classpath="org.testng.TestNG">     ---------> It produces 
 error in this stmt 
 <classpath>
 <pathelement location="../lib/testng-6.2.jar"/>
 </classpath>
 </taskdef>
 <property name="testng.output.dir" value="testngOutput"/>
 <path id="classes">
 <fileset dir="../lib">
  <include name="*.jar"/>
 </fileset>
 <pathelement location="${bin.dir}"/>
 </path>
 <mkdir dir="${testng.output.dir}"/>
 <testng outputdir="${testng.output.dir}" classpathref="classes">  
 <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/>  
 </testng> </target>
<target name="stopServer">
 <echo message="stop selenium server. Plz wait"/>
 <get taskname="selenium-shutdown" 
 src="http://localhost:4444/selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2/driver/?cmd=shutDown"
 dest="./out/sever.stop.status.txt" ignoreerrors="true"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Can any one help me out 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class implementing the data type in the 'classname' attribute.
According to the Ant [taskdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html) documentation (and more specifically [typedef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html)), this task has two required attributes - 'name' and 'classname', unless 'file' or 'resource' have been specified. The attribute 'classpath' only defines the locations where the class specified in 'classname' can be found.